# Passing arguments in function pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a function to grab data from my database. I want this function to be reusable just by placing correct arguments for different tables. Here's what I've done :

```
public function selectdata($table, $arguments='*', $where = null){
  if($this->isconnect){

        //check whether users put column names in the select clause

        if(is_array($arguments)){

            $new_args = implode(',', $arguments);
            $sql      = 'SELECT '.$new_args.' FROM '.$table;

        } else {

            $sql      = 'SELECT '.$arguments.' FROM '.$table;

        }

        //check whether users use the where clause

        if($where != null && is_array($where)){

            $where  = implode(' ', $where);
            $sql   .= ' WHERE '.$where ;

        } 

        $query  = $this->db->query($sql);
        $query  -> SetFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        while($row = $query->fetch()){
            print_r($row);
        }


    } else {
        echo 'failed, moron';
    }
}
```

And this is the way to run the function :

```
$columnname   = array('bookname');
$where        = array('bookid','=','2');
echo $database-> selectdata('buku', $columnname, $where);
```

The code worked quite decently so far, but I'm wondering how I want to use `$where` but without `$columnname` in the function. How do I pass the arguments in the function?

And could you point to me the better way to create a function to grab data using PDO?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use a PDO class which can look like this:

```
<?php
class DB_Connect{
    var $dbh;
    function __construct(){
        $host = "xxx";
        $db = "xxx";
        $user = "xxx";
        $password = "xxx";
        $this -> dbh = $this -> db_connect($host, $db, $user, $password);
    }
    public function getDBConnection(){
        return $this -> dbh;
    }
    protected function db_connect($host, $db, $user, $password){
        //var_dump($host, $db, $user, $password);exit();
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
        }
        catch(PDOException $err) {
            echo "Error: ".$err->getMessage()."<br/>";
            die();
        }
        return $dbh;
    }
    public function query($statement){
        $keyword = substr(strtoupper($statement), 0, strpos($statement, " "));
        $dbh = $this->getDBConnection();        
        if($dbh){
            try{
                $sql = $dbh->prepare($statement);
                $exe = $sql->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $err){
                return $err->getMessage();
            }
            switch($keyword){
                case "SELECT":                  
                    $result = array();
                    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){                        
                        $result[] = $row;                       
                    }
                    return $result;                 
                    break;
                default: 
                    return $exe;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now you can include that class and create an object with `$dbh = new DB_Connect;` and call every statement you want just with the reference on `$dbh->query($statement)`
This is my prefered way to do this.

EDIT: If you want to use a statement on another Database, just use the `__construct($db)` method to pass your database name on object creation

Comment: what's the functions of the `$keyword` variable?

Comment: The `$keyword` variable is to seperate if the result needs to be fetched! With that you get a well formatted array like `$array["counter"]["Field_Key"]` back if you select something from your database. (The "counter" is the number of results you get starting with `0`)

Comment: @januaryananda was it the answere your were looking for?